# I'm getting a 'gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound' and not sure why

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread, oauth2client

I've been using GoogleAPIs for a while now but still fairly new to most concepts. I haven't had any issues until now.

My google sheet is accessible by the `client_email`, my `client_secret.json`file is in the proper directory, and there are no typos in the reference to the sheet name in my code, however it randomly started giving me a `'gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound'` and I can't figure out what the issue is.

The only thing that has changed from the time I wasn't getting the error to now is I changed the location of the sheet to a different Google Drive so I'm assuming it has to do with that, I'm just not sure what I need to do to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there are any questions I could answer.

Comment: can you show the code that gives the error?

Comment: can you show the code that gives the error?